# Remove duplicates in the list using linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects, generic-list

I have a class `Items` with `properties (Id, Name, Code, Price)`.

The List of `Items` is populated with duplicated items.

For ex.:

```
1         Item1       IT00001        $100
2         Item2       IT00002        $200
3         Item3       IT00003        $150
1         Item1       IT00001        $100
3         Item3       IT00003        $150
```

How to remove the duplicates in the list using linq?

Comment: I have another class as property in the Items Class also

Comment: You can also do `var set = new HashSet<int>(); var uniques = items.Where(x => set.Add(x.Id));`. It should be criminal to do so..

Comment: I agree.. ForEach should be used instead :)

Answer (score 461, accepted):

```
var distinctItems = items.Distinct();
```

To match on only some of the properties, create a custom equality comparer, e.g.:

```
class DistinctItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item> {

    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y) {
        return x.Id == y.Id &&
            x.Name == y.Name &&
            x.Code == y.Code &&
            x.Price == y.Price;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Item obj) {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode() ^
            obj.Name.GetHashCode() ^
            obj.Code.GetHashCode() ^
            obj.Price.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var distinctItems = items.Distinct(new DistinctItemComparer());
```

Comment: Hi Christian , What will be the change in code if i have a List<my_Custom_Class> and List<string>. My custom class has various items in which one is DCN number and list<string> has only DCN number. So I need to check the List<Custom_Class> contains any dcn from List<string>. For example suppose List1 = List<Custom_Class> and List2 = List<String>. If List1 has 2000 items and list2 has 40000 items on which 600 items from List1 exists in List2. So in this case i need 1400 as my output List as list1. So what would be the expression. Thanks in advance

Comment: Also one more case is here since List1 contains various items , other items values might be different but the DCN must be same. So in my case Distinct failed to give desired out put.

Comment: I find comparer classes extremely useful. They can express logic other than simple property name comparisons. I wrote a new one last month, to do something that `GroupBy` could not.

Comment: Works well and got me to learn something new and investigate the `XoR` operator `^` in C#. Had used in VB.NET via `Xor` but had to do a double take to your code to see what it was at first.

Comment: This is the error I get when I try to use Distinct Comparer: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[DataAccess.HR.Dao.CCS_LOCATION_TBL] Distinct[CCS_LOCATION_TBL](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[DataAccess.HR.Dao.CCS_LOCATION_TBL], System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[DataAccess.HR.Dao.CCS_LOCATION_TBL])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: OK had to add AsEnumerable, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424227/error-on-iequalitycomparert

Comment: LINQ to Entities doesn't support methods that use IEqualityComparer. [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities).

Comment: Stuff like this is what makes me love C#

Comment: @KolobCanyon It is used in hash table lookups. There is a good write-up at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4096774/115413

Answer (score 752):

```
var distinctItems = items.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(y => y.First());
```

Comment: Thanks - was looking to avoid writing a comparer class so I'm glad this works :)

Comment: +1 This solution even allows for a tie-breaker: eliminate duplicates with criteria!

Comment: But a little overhead!

Comment: But, as Victor Juri suggested below: use FirstorDefault. can not believe, that solution can be so simple (without  custom equality comparer)

Comment: You can group with multiple properties :
List<XYZ> MyUniqueList = MyList.GroupBy(x => new { x.Column1, x.Column2 }).Select(g=> g.First()).ToList();

Comment: @SumitJoshi thanks this solution worked when comparing two observable collections of my custom type as well!

Answer (score 48):

If there is something that is throwing off your Distinct query, you might want to look at [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) and use the DistinctBy operator and select distinct objects by id.

```
var distinct = items.DistinctBy( i => i.Id );
```

Comment: There is no DistinctBy() method with Linq.

Comment: @FereydoonBarikzehy But he is not talking about pure Linq. In post is linq to MoreLinq project ...

Comment: In .NET 6+ there is now DistinctBy()

Answer (score 34):

This is how I was able to group by with Linq. Hope it helps.

```
var query = collection.GroupBy(x => x.title).Select(y => y.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: @nawfal, I was suggesting FirstOrDefault() in lieu of First()

Comment: If I am correct, using `FirstOrDefault` here offers no benefit if the `Select` immediately follows `GroupBy`, since there's no possibility of there being an empty group (the groups were _just derived_ from the collection's contents)

Answer (score 29):

An universal extension method:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        return enumerable.GroupBy(keySelector).Select(grp => grp.First());
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
var lstDst = lst.DistinctBy(item => item.Key);
```

Comment: Very clean approach

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for, works well.

Comment: perfect in addition with @Salah Akbari solution : 
`result = result.DistinctBy(r => new { r.NDA, r.Event, r.MovementDate, r.EventDate }).ToList();`

Answer (score 21):

You have three option here for removing duplicate item in your List:

1. Use a a custom equality comparer and then use `Distinct(new DistinctItemComparer())` as [@Christian Hayter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1606686/2946329) mentioned.
2. Use `GroupBy`, but please note in `GroupBy` you should Group by all of the columns because if you just group by `Id` it doesn't remove duplicate items always. For example consider the following example:

   ```
   List<Item> a = new List<Item>
   {
       new Item {Id = 1, Name = "Item1", Code = "IT00001", Price = 100},
       new Item {Id = 2, Name = "Item2", Code = "IT00002", Price = 200},
       new Item {Id = 3, Name = "Item3", Code = "IT00003", Price = 150},
       new Item {Id = 1, Name = "Item1", Code = "IT00001", Price = 100},
       new Item {Id = 3, Name = "Item3", Code = "IT00003", Price = 150},
       new Item {Id = 3, Name = "Item3", Code = "IT00004", Price = 250}
   };
   var distinctItems = a.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(y => y.First());
   ```

   The result for this grouping will be:

   ```
   {Id = 1, Name = "Item1", Code = "IT00001", Price = 100}
   {Id = 2, Name = "Item2", Code = "IT00002", Price = 200}
   {Id = 3, Name = "Item3", Code = "IT00003", Price = 150}
   ```

   Which is incorrect because it considers `{Id = 3, Name = "Item3", Code = "IT00004", Price = 250}` as duplicate. So the correct query would be:

   ```
   var distinctItems = a.GroupBy(c => new { c.Id , c.Name , c.Code , c.Price})
                        .Select(c => c.First()).ToList();
   ```

   3.Override `Equal` and `GetHashCode` in item class:

   ```
   public class Item
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Code { get; set; }
       public int Price { get; set; }

       public override bool Equals(object obj)
       {
           if (!(obj is Item))
               return false;
           Item p = (Item)obj;
           return (p.Id == Id && p.Name == Name && p.Code == Code && p.Price == Price);
       }
       public override int GetHashCode()
       {
           return String.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}", Id, Name, Code, Price).GetHashCode();
       }
   }
   ```

   Then you can use it like this:

   ```
   var distinctItems = a.Distinct();
   ```

Answer (score 17):

Use `Distinct()` but keep in mind that it uses the default equality comparer to compare values, so if you want anything beyond that you need to implement your own comparer.

Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx for an example.

Comment: I should notice that default comparer works if collection member types is one of value types. But which default equality comparer select by csc for reference types. Reference types must have own comparer(s).

Answer (score 6):

Try this extension method out. Hopefully this could help.

```
public static class DistinctHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        var identifiedKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
        return source.Where(element => identifiedKeys.Add(keySelector(element)));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var outputList = sourceList.DistinctBy(x => x.TargetProperty);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>()
{
    new Employee{Id =1,Name="AAAAA"}
    , new Employee{Id =2,Name="BBBBB"}
    , new Employee{Id =3,Name="AAAAA"}
    , new Employee{Id =4,Name="CCCCC"}
    , new Employee{Id =5,Name="AAAAA"}
};

List<Employee> duplicateEmployees = employees.Except(employees.GroupBy(i => i.Name)
                                             .Select(ss => ss.FirstOrDefault()))
                                            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround, not beautiful but working.

I have an XML file with an element called "MEMDES" with two attributes "GRADE" and "SPD" to record the RAM module information.
There is a lot of duplicate items in SPD.

So here is the code I use to remove the duplicated items:

```cs
IEnumerable<XElement> MList =
    from RAMList in PREF.Descendants("MEMDES")
    where (string)RAMList.Attribute("GRADE") == "DDR4"
    select RAMList;

List<string> sellist = new List<string>();

foreach (var MEMList in MList)
{
    sellist.Add((string)MEMList.Attribute("SPD").Value);
}

foreach (string slist in sellist.Distinct())
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(slist);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you don't want to write IEqualityComparer you can try something like following.

```
 class Program
{

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var items = new List<Item>();
        items.Add(new Item {Id = 1, Name = "Item1"});
        items.Add(new Item {Id = 2, Name = "Item2"});
        items.Add(new Item {Id = 3, Name = "Item3"});

        //Duplicate item
        items.Add(new Item {Id = 4, Name = "Item4"});
        //Duplicate item
        items.Add(new Item {Id = 2, Name = "Item2"});

        items.Add(new Item {Id = 3, Name = "Item3"});

        var res = items.Select(i => new {i.Id, i.Name})
            .Distinct().Select(x => new Item {Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name}).ToList();

        // now res contains distinct records
    }



}


public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```