# Filtering an array with duplicate elements

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, duplicates

I have an array of FileInfo objects with duplicate elements I'd like to filter, i.e.e remove duplicates, the elements are sorted by last write time using a custom comparer.  The format of the file names is as follows:

**file{number}*{YYYMMDD}*{HHMMSS}.txt**

What I'd like to know is if there's an elegant way of filtering out two files with the same file number so that only the most recent is present in the list, i.e. I have two elements in my array with the following file names:

**file1_20110214_090020.txt**

**file1_20101214_090020.txt**

I would like to keep the most recent version of **file1**.  The code I have for getting the files is as follows:

```
 FileInfo[] listOfFiles = diSearch.GetFiles(fileSearch);
 IComparer compare = new FileComparer(FileComparer.CompareBy.LastWriteTime);
 Array.Sort(listOfFiles, compare);
```

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE:

Forgot to add the caveat, the program in question is using .Net 2.0, so no LINQ unfortunately.  Sorry for the confusion, above I corrected the file number to be the same

Comment: Not completely clear. You said, `"file1_..."` and `"file2_..."` have the same number, so just keep `file1` 'cause is more recent. As far as I can see they have different number...

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606679/remove-duplicates-in-the-list-using-linq, using `array.Distinct()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With LINQ, you could do:

```
var listOfFiles = diSearch
                  .GetFiles(fileSearch)
                  .GroupBy(file => file.Name.Substring(file.Name.IndexOf('_')))
                  .Select(g => g.OrderBy(file => file.LastWriteTime).Last())
                  .ToArray();
```

If you want these files to also be ordered by last write-time, put in a `.OrderByDescending(file => file.LastWriteTime)` before the `ToArray` call.

You could of course use a more efficient technique to find the latest file from each group, such as with a [`MaxBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) operator.

**EDIT**:

In .NET 2.0, you could construct a `Dictionary<string, List<FileInfo>>` (with the key being the 'file-group') from the array, and then extract the latest file from *each* list of the dictionary's `Values` collection, to produce the result.

If you are on C# 3 or later, another option would be to use [LINQBridge](http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/), which lets you use LINQ to Objects while targeting .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to determine the most recent file as determined by its **file name** (YYYYMMM and so on) not by the last write time and grouped by file id write time. In this case this would work:

```
var mostRecentFiles = listOfFiles.GroupBy( f => f.Name.Substring(0, f.Name.IndexOf("_")))
                                 .Select( g => g.OrderByDescending( f => 
                                         { string[] s =f.Name.Split(new [] {'_', '.'}); return Convert.ToDecimal(s[1]+s[2]);}).First())
                                 .ToList();
```