# SQL - How can I remove duplicate rows by last entered value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have this code from this link: [How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

```
 ;WITH cte
 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id, date_work, hours
                                   ORDER BY ( SELECT 0)) RN
     FROM   work_hours)
 DELETE FROM cte
 WHERE  RN > 1
```

Is it possible to remove first entered row of duplicate or i should have an extra column `date_of_entry`? I want to do this if i entered same date_work and different hours `PARTITION BY person_id, date_work` it remove randomly duplicates.

If it isn't possible, how can i remove duplicates with higher hours?

Comment: Unless you reserve a column for it, there is no way to know the last inserted row. +1 on effort though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `order by hours desc`

```
;WITH cte
 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id, date_work
                                   ORDER BY hours DESC) RN
     FROM   work_hours)
 DELETE FROM cte
 WHERE  RN > 1
```

Comment: **`ORDER BY hours desc`** is acceptable answer, it deletes duplicate column with lower number of hours. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 4):

Yes - you or have to introduce date_of_entry field or some other vector field like `IDENTITY`. For example if column `Id` is your `INT IDENTITY`, then your query will look like this:

```
 ;WITH cte
 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id, date_work, hours
                                   ORDER BY ( SELECT Id DESC)) RN
     FROM   work_hours)
 DELETE FROM cte
 WHERE  RN > 1
```

**Of course** it is valid if nobody changes the values in `IDENTITY` column

And if your conditions suits - then you may want to use column `Hours` as your vector field within grouping range of `person_id, date_work`

**And even better way** is to have an `UNIQUE INDEX` over columns `person_id, date_work, hours`, then there will no any ability to add duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it also with LINQ to SQL [Remove duplicates in the list using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606679/remove-duplicates-in-the-list-using-linq) , SQL with GROUP BY http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/removing-duplicates-from-a-table-in-sql-server/ , and SQL DISTINCT http://www.databasedev.co.uk/eliminate_duplicates.html .