# How can I use Lambda syntax to remove duplicates?

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove duplicates in the list using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606679/remove-duplicates-in-the-list-using-linq)

I'm trying to remove duplicates from an `IQueryable` collection. I'm thinking that I need to do some sort of nested select but I'm not really sure. I created a script in linqpad that has the original list with duplicate items both expanded and collapsed.

What I want to do is select the items from my `listWithDuplicates` that are not in the `dupesAsList`. I also want to keep the record with the highest id in the `listWithDuplicates` if its found to be duplicating...

Wondered if someone could help or tell me best way to remove duplicates?

```
void Main()
{
    var listWithDuplicates = new List<Tuple<int,string>>();
    listWithDuplicates.Add(new Tuple<int,string>(1,"Dog"));
    listWithDuplicates.Add(new Tuple<int,string>(2,"Cat"));
    listWithDuplicates.Add(new Tuple<int,string>(3,"Dog"));
    listWithDuplicates.Add(new Tuple<int,string>(4,"Chicken"));
    listWithDuplicates.Add(new Tuple<int,string>(5,"Dog"));
    listWithDuplicates.Add(new Tuple<int,string>(6,"Dog"));
    listWithDuplicates.Add(new Tuple<int,string>(7,"Chicken"));

    var dupesAsList = listWithDuplicates.GroupBy(s => s.Item2).SelectMany(grp => grp.Skip(1));

    var dupesGrouped = listWithDuplicates.GroupBy(s => s.Item2).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Select(x => x.Key);

    dupesAsList.Dump();

    dupesGrouped.Dump();
}
```

NOTE : I need to do this with a lambda expression not query syntax!

Comment: Is it just the string that makes it a duplicate?

Comment: sorry Konrad I actually want to use Lamda syntax....

Comment: Yeah, there is a perfect lambda syntax answer in that question - you just gotta look. This is a duplicate question...

Comment: Are you trying to produce the list of removed items in addition to the list without duplicates, or is `dupesAsList` a by-product of your strategy?

Comment: Please look at what im asking and what you have all incorrectly marked as duplicate. How do I remove the dupes that arent of the highest id in the original? hmm, thanks for not giving me the answer and closing my question!