# how to select the latest date from a IQueryable.GroupBy?

Tags: c#, linq

I got the code below from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606679/remove-duplicates-in-the-list-using-linq)

```
    var distinctAllEvaluationLicenses = allEvaluationLicenses.GroupBy((License => 
License.dateCreated)).Select(License => License.First());
```

How can I select the latest 'dateCreated' instead of the First one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is the max `dateCreated`, try this:

```
var results = allEvaluationLicenses.Max(x => x.dateCreated);
```

If you want the licenses with the max `dateCreated`, try this:

```
var results =
    allEvaluationLicenses.GroupBy(x => x.dateCreated)
                         .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
                         .First();
```

Or in query syntax:

```
var results =
    (from l in allEvaluationLicenses
     group l by l.dateCreated into g
     orderby g.Key descending
     select g)
    .First();
```

Comment: Thanks @p.s.w.g, I used the second one

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Max` to get the largest of a sequence.

```
var distinctAllEvaluationLicenses = allEvaluationLicenses.GroupBy(License => 
License.dateCreated)
    .Max(group => group.Key);
```

That said, in this particular context, there doesn't seem to be any reason to do the grouping at all:

```
var distinctAllEvaluationLicenses = allEvaluationLicenses
    .Max(License=> License.dateCreated)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be what the OP wants, in that you are getting the Date; the OP seems to want the group of License objects that corresponds to the date.

Comment: Thanks Servy. I had to group them because the database wasn't designed well hence there are duplicates where the only difference is the datecreated so I had get the latest one