# How to group a IQueryable by property 1 but order by property 2?

Tags: c#, linq

Following from my question previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283342/how-to-select-the-latest-date-from-a-iqueryable-groupby)

I used

```
var distinctAllEvaluationLicenses = allEvaluationLicenses.GroupBy((License => License.dateCreated)).OrderByDescending(lics => lics.Key).First();
```

To group the IQueryable

```
allEvaluationLicenses
```

by using License's property 1 which is 'dateCreated'

But now, how can I order them by using a different property such as 'nLicenceID'?

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
var distinctAllEvaluationLicenses = allEvaluationLicenses.GroupBy((License => License.dateCreated)).OrderByDescending(lics => (sort by nLicenseID here) ).First();
```

Comment: Do you want to sort all of the groups, if so, what if the items in a group don't all have the same `nLicenseID `, what do you do?  Or do you mean sorting by that value within each group?

Comment: What's stopping you from doing `lics.Id` in the order-by lambda?

Comment: "what if the items in a group don't all have the same nLicenseID" -- Yes Im aware of this, I just want to know this -> "do you mean sorting by that value within each group?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For LINQ-to-Objects, the objects *inside* each group retain the ordering in which they are discovered:

> The `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` objects are yielded in an order based on the order of the elements in source that produced the first key of each `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`. Elements in a grouping are yielded in the order they appear in source.

So: if your aim is to order the **contents** of each group, simply order the source:

```
var distinctAllEvaluationLicenses = allEvaluationLicenses
    .OrderByDescending({whatever})
    .GroupBy({etc}).First();
```

Note that this is not guaranteed to work for other LINQ sources, and note that it doesn't influence the order in which the *groups* are presented. To do that you could perhaps do something like:

```
var distinctAllEvaluationLicenses = allEvaluationLicenses
    .GroupBy({etc}).
    .OrderBy(grp => grp.Min(item => x.SomeProp)).First();
```

which would present the *groups* in order of the minimum `SomeProp` in each. Obviously adjust to max / etc as necessary.

Comment: He specifically said this is an `IQueryable`, so it's *not* linq to objects.  It's linq to sql (based on the previous question)

Comment: @Servy `IQueryable` doesn't tell us anything about the source. LINQ-to-Objects can be exposed as `IQueryable`. Oddly enough, via `.AsQueryable`. Now, the "previous question" bit - that's fine, but I'm answering *this* question, not the previous one.

Comment: As I said, as per the previous questions by this user on this issue, it's linq to sql, not linq to objects.  Even if you didn't know that, the answer should (ideally) apply to any query provider if none is specified, not just one particular (and a rather unlikely) query provider.

Answer (score 0):

To sort the items within the group you can use `Select`:

```
var distinctAllEvaluationLicenses = allEvaluationLicenses.GroupBy(License => License.dateCreated)
    .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(item => item.nLicenceID));
```