# Remove duplicates from a List<Object> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

The question is straightforward and a simple search in SO gives a number of similar questions but I'm still struggling to get an answer for this.

I want to remove the **duplicate objects** from `List<Column> columns` based on all the properties they have. The `Column` class itself has a `List<string>` property and this is where I think I have problems maybe in the `GetHashCode()` or `Equals` part.

Here is the full code I've written but I'm not getting the correct results. For example in the code below, I want to remove column3 because it is the same as column1 in every aspect.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Arrays
{
    public class ColumnList
    {
        public static void RemoveDuplicateColumnTypes()
        {
            // define columns
            var column1 = new Column
            {
                StartElevation = 0,
                EndElevation = 310,
                ListOfSections = new List<string> { "C50", "C40" }
            };
            var column2 = new Column
            {
                StartElevation = 0,
                EndElevation = 310,
                ListOfSections = new List<string> { "C50", "C30" }
            };
            var column3 = new Column
            {
                StartElevation = 0,
                EndElevation = 310,
                ListOfSections = new List<string> { "C50", "C40"}
            };

            // list of columns
            var columns = new List<Column> { column1, column2, column3 };

            var result = columns.Distinct(new ColumnListComparer());
        }
    }

    public class ColumnListComparer : IEqualityComparer<Column>
    {
        public bool Equals(Column x, Column y)
        {
            if (x == null || y == null) return false;

            if (Math.Abs(x.StartElevation - y.StartElevation) < 0.001 &&
                Math.Abs(x.EndElevation - y.EndElevation) < 0.001 &&
                x.ListOfSections.SequenceEqual(y.ListOfSections))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Column obj)
        {
            return obj.StartElevation.GetHashCode() ^
                   obj.EndElevation.GetHashCode() ^
                   obj.ListOfSections.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    public class Column
    {
        public double StartElevation { get; set; }
        public double EndElevation { get; set; }
        public List<string> ListOfSections { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think firstly you should override `Equal` method of `Column` Class, to call it so easy in lambda expressions, then loop throw the list and remove each item if already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash code for the lists is not going to match. So the whole hash code won't match.

Try this:

```
 public int GetHashCode(Column obj)
 {
     return 42;
 }
```

Hash codes must be equal if the objects are equal. It is not ideal in general to return a fixed number, but it is entitily valid. Why 42? Hitch hikers fan.

If that works, then you can look for a better hash function that actually uses some of the values in the list.

How complex you make the hash function is up to you as long as you follow the golden rule of objects are equal, their hash functions must be equal.

Here is for example a valid hash function that just takes into account the length of the list:

```
 public int GetHashCode(Column obj)
 {
    return obj.ListOfSections.Count;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but why 42? Then it will return the same for all? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Recommendation to return 42 is a very bad one, because it degrades hash table performance to the levels lower than the performance of a plain list. The second recommendation is a little better, but the count may not offer enough diversity to give you a significant speed-up compared to a linear search.

Comment: It wasn't a recommendation, so much as a thing to try to prove the hash is broken. If it works they can improve the hash function.

Comment: @weston This is absolutely working. But I can't understand why we are defining a GetHashCode() in the first place if we are going to return an arbitrary number like 42? what is happening here?

Answer (score 2):

Change your `GetHashCode` as below.

```
public int GetHashCode(Column obj)
{
    unchecked
    {
        var hashCode = obj.StartElevation.GetHashCode();
        hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ obj.EndElevation.GetHashCode();
        foreach (var item in obj.ListOfSections)
        {
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ item.GetHashCode();
        }
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

Your version doesn't work because `ListOfSections.GetHashCode` is indeterminant, which may return anything as it is used to check for reference equality but we're dealing with value equality here. So you **must** generate hashcode based on "Value equality"

Comment: But the hash code of the doubles is also inconsistent with the equals method.

Comment: @weston You have any clue about how to solve it? Am working on it

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Is the problem with doubles already solved in the above answer?

Comment: @Vahid Sadly no :( I can't come with immediate solution to that problem. let me get back If I get any idea.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I just can't understand why returning 42 is working! But there are lots of answers in this page. If the answer is so concise why to go all the way to do all these complex things?

Comment: @Vahid Because returning a fixed number is poor performing. It will result in `O(n)` operation rather than `O(1)`. To understand this you need to understand [why hash codes are for](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx?Redirected=true).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thanks so much, so other than performance issues it won't have any other problems? Cause I only have 200-300 columns to compare.

Comment: @Vahid Absolutely nothing. If you're not worried about performance you can easily ignore `StartElevation` and `EndElevation` part in `GetHashCode`. That should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the culprit:

```
return obj.StartElevation.GetHashCode() ^
       obj.EndElevation.GetHashCode() ^
       obj.ListOfSections.GetHashCode(); // <<== This line
```

Lists do not base their hash code on the hash codes of their elements. Two different lists with identical element would not have the same hash code. Change this to a line that aggregates the hash codes of list members to make it work:

```
return 31*31*obj.StartElevation.GetHashCode() +
       31*obj.EndElevation.GetHashCode() +
       obj.ListOfSections.Aggregate((p, v) => 31*p + v.GetHashCode());
```

Note: Although this will make your code eliminate `cell3`, **your code would remain invalid**. The reason is not so obvious - the problem you will have is that your `Equals` method is not transitive, due to the fact that you compare doubles by allowing their differences be within a tolerance `0.001` to be considered equal. A consequence of this is that

```
Cell1 == Cell2 && Cell2 == Cell3
```

no longer imply that

```
Cell1 == Cell3
```

This is fundamentally wrong.

Moreover, it means that two objects that your algorithm considers equal may have different hash codes. The contract of the equality comparer prohibits this.

In order to fix this problem, switch away from representing elevations as `double`, and use `int` or `long` to store elevations expressed in units that are 1000 times smaller than the units that you currently have. In other words, if your code stores an elevation as a double `123.456`, the new code should store an integer `123456`. This would let you compare for equality with the right degree of tolerance. When you obtain the elevation for external use, cast the number to `double` and divide by 1000 to produce the old result.

Comment: But the hash code of the doubles is also inconsistent with the equals method.

Comment: @weston I was typing that up. Hash code of double is not what prevented his current code from doing what he expects, but it is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: another problem is that his hashcode method does not multiply the value with a prime number. That means that any order of elements will return the same hashcode

Comment: Remember this is a equalitycompareres Hashcode. It's job is to quickly ruleout equality. If you include everything that's in the equals, then it's no better than returning a fixed number.

Comment: @weston That assumption is fundamentally wrong. To see why, consider what happens when you hash 10,000 objects, when each object has three fields in its list.

Comment: Yes, I take that back. The Hashcode can be calculated once. And the fewer hash collisions, the fewer full equals calculations required.

Answer (score -1):

`HashSet<T>` only adds unique items.

or

```
List<T> withDupes = LoadSomeData();
List<T> noDupes = withDupes.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably you need HasSet

Override GetHashCode and Equals method in your Column class

Add your objects to HashSet and you will get unique set.

for e.g. var columns = new HashSet(columnList);

Below is the example using string

```
        public void ListToHashSet()
    {
        var list = new List<string> { "abc", "efg", "abc", "efg" };
        var set = new HashSet<string>(list);
        foreach (var item in list)
            Console.WriteLine("list:{0}", item);

        foreach (var item in set)
            Console.WriteLine("set:{0}", item);
    }
```

And check the output, as for .net string class already has override for GetHashCode and Equals you don't need to implement, but for custom class you will need to override both, Gethashcode for storing and retrieving from HashTable and GetEqual for equality of two object.