# LINQ Solution for Multiple Resolves

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of `MyClass`, which can be simplified as follow:

```
public class MyClass {
    public int Id;
    public string Origin;
    public int Points;
    public DateTime RequestTime;
    public MyClass(int id, string origin, int points, DateTime requestTime) {
        Id = id;
        Origin = origin;
        Points = points;
        RequestTime = requestTime;
    }
}
```

Now, in the `Array`, without any errors from the user side or throughout the input process, there cannot be `MyClass` instance with identical `Id` and `Origin`.

However, if there be any, I should resolve it. And here are the resolving rules:

1. Firstly by `Points` - that is, to take **one** among the duplicates which has the highest `Points`
2. But if the `Points` are the same, I have to further resolve it by using `RequestTime` - the latest will be taken.
3. And if, there is no difference in `RequestTime`, then I can take one of the duplicates arbitrarily.

Here is the sample data input I have:

```
MyClass[] myarr = new MyClass[] {
    new MyClass(1, "Ware House 1", 5, new DateTime(2016, 1, 26, 14, 0, 0)), //[0]
    new MyClass(1, "Ware House 1", 7, new DateTime(2016, 1, 26, 14, 0, 0)), //[1] //higher points
    new MyClass(1, "Ware House 2", 7, new DateTime(2016, 1, 26, 14, 0, 0)), //[2]
    new MyClass(1, "Ware House 2", 7, new DateTime(2016, 1, 26, 14, 1, 0)), //[3] //later time
    new MyClass(1, "Ware House 2", 7, new DateTime(2016, 1, 26, 14, 0, 0)), //[4]
    new MyClass(2, "Ware House 2", 7, new DateTime(2016, 1, 26, 14, 0, 0)), //[5] //higher points
    new MyClass(2, "Ware House 2", 5, new DateTime(2016, 1, 26, 14, 1, 0)), //[6] //later time but less points
    new MyClass(3, "Ware House 1", 6, new DateTime(2016, 1, 26, 14, 0, 0)), //[7] //triplet, pick any
    new MyClass(3, "Ware House 1", 6, new DateTime(2016, 1, 26, 14, 0, 0)), //[8] //triplet, pick any
    new MyClass(3, "Ware House 1", 6, new DateTime(2016, 1, 26, 14, 0, 0)) //[9] //triplet, pick any
};
```

The final result should be `[1], [3], [5], + any of [7]/[8]/[9]`

I want to implement `LINQ` solution for it, but stuck. I do not know how make query it at once.

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Group by {`Id`, `Origin`} and take the first one *from each group* when ordered by `Points` and `RequestTime`:

```
var query = from x in myarr
    group x by new {x.Id, x.Origin}
    into g
    select (
        from z in g
        orderby z.Points descending, z.RequestTime descending
        select z).First();
```

In method syntax, this is:

```
var query =
    myarr.GroupBy(x => new {x.Id, x.Origin})
         .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(z => z.Points)
                       .ThenByDescending(z => z.RequestTime)
                       .First());
```

Comment: ah, I can see that the trick is to `group by` both the Id and Origin before decendingly ordering it twice. I did not know before that we could group by two items. I was thinking of doing double `GroupBy` which did not seem to be good idea because of the nature of the "composite key". Thanks a lot again! :)

Comment: @Ian Yep, anonymous types are your friend in grouping and joining.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
myarr.OrderBy(m=> m.Points).ToList();
```

or

```
myarr.OrderBy(m=> m.Points).Orderby(m=> m.RequestTime);
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer... To order it alone is not difficult, but where I was stuck was when I tried to remove duplicates based on the resolving rules. Any idea?

Comment: dit you see following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606679/remove-duplicates-in-the-list-using-linq