# how to check if there is no highest value in a dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have a dictionary like this.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dictionary.Add(string, int);
....
....
```

To get the key of the highest value of a dictionary in c#, I wrote as below.

```
String maxKey = dictionary.Aggregate((l, r) => l.Value > r.Value ? l : r).Key;
```

Currently I get below result using above code.

In Case 1, maxKey is "BBB"

```
dictionary =>   [0] {["AAA",0]]
        [1] {["BBB",1]]
        [2] {["CCC",0]]
```

In Case 2, maxKey is "BBB"

```
dictionary =>   [0] {["AAA",1]]
        [1] {["BBB",1]]
        [2] {["CCC",0]]
```

In Case 3, maxKey is "CCC"

```
dictionary =>   [0] {["AAA",0]]
        [1] {["BBB",0]]
        [2] {["CCC",0]]
```

If there is no highest value in a dictionary (if the highest value found more than one time, it's not mean as "max value") , I want to return null or "".

If there is highest value in a dictionary, I want to return key of the highest value.

Can anybody tell me a better way to do this?

Comment: How do you define no highest value - is it when all values are same or something else?

Comment: How do you define `no highest value`? If all are the same / all are `0` or if more than x of them have the same highest value? If more than one has `the highest value`, which one wins? The last, the one with the `highest` Key/ etc ?

Comment: probably the highest value must be unique

Comment: @mihail case 2 has 2 values with value `1` and `BBB` is returned.

Comment: @mihail Not according to the examples. They don't cover everything though so a `definition` from OP would be nice

Comment: You probably could group the keys after ordering and check if the first key has member > 1

Comment: @Ian Although that's a possibility, I think it's best not to speculate and wait for an answer from OP. There are way to many ways to interpret this question.

Comment: `If there is no highest value in a dictionary, I want to return null or "".` - I understand it as if the max value found occurs more than once it's not considered as "max value"

Comment: Sorry I made confuse my question. As @mihail said, I want to return null or something if the max value found more than one time.

Comment: @Sandar Min Aye So your case 2 example is invalid?

Comment: in this case you probably want to remove all duplicates from your dictionary - refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606679/remove-duplicates-in-the-list-using-linq

Comment: or to be more accurate, find some max key, remove the duplicates and check if the max key you have is still presented when you have removed the duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
var maxKey = dictionary.Aggregate((l, r) => l.Value > r.Value ? l : r);

if(dictionary.Values.Where(x=>x == maxKey.Value).Count() >1)
{
    ...
    return null;
} 

return maxKey.Key;
```

Answer (score 0):

Write another line.

```
var maxkv = dictionary.Aggregate((l, r) => l.Value > r.Value ? l : r);
var maxKey = dictionary.Where(k => k.Value == maxkv.Value).Take(2).Count() > 1 ? null : maxkv.Key;
```

This will throw exception if your dictionary is empty so do check for length before this if necessary.

```
if(dictionary.Count == 0) return; // or some guard like this.
```

If your dictionary is not empty then you will always have at least one item to take. try to take another item (`Take(2)`) so if count becomes `2` means there are two or more equal keys with max value.

Comment: isnt it better to check `>1` instead of `==2`...

Comment: @mihail there will be no difference.

Comment: actually you're right, missed the `Take(2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GroupBy` to group the items based on their `Value`, then get the Group with highest value and check for Items Count

```
var Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
int? maxValue = null;
var MaxGroup = Dictionary.GroupBy(a => a.Value).OrderBy(a=>a.Key).First();
if (MaxGroup.Count() == 1)
{
    maxValue = MaxGroup.Key;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int> {{"AAA", 1},{"BBB", 0}, {"CCC", 1}};
int maxValue = dictionary.Values.Max();
var maxKVs = dictionary.Where(kv => kv.Value == maxValue);
string keyMax = null;
if (maxKVs.Count() == 1)
{
    keyMax = maxKVs.First().Key;
}
else
{
    // Multiple items with value equals to max
}
```

It will store the max value of the dictionary then count how many items have the same value and assign `keyMax` if only one item have this value.

---

If you want to browse the dictionary only once, use this foreach:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int> {{"AAA", 1},{"BBB", 0}, {"CCC", 1}};
int maxValue = Int32.MinValue;
string maxKey = null;
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> keyValuePair in dictionary)
{
    if (keyValuePair.Value > maxValue)
    {
        maxValue = keyValuePair.Value;
        maxKey = keyValuePair.Key;
    }
    else if (keyValuePair.Value == maxValue)
    {
        maxKey = null; // not max, reset key
    }
}
```

Comment: This will iterate through `dictionary` 3 times..