# Merging duplicate strings in List and summing them

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a list of strings like following which I fill and group currently like this:

```
public static List<CustomDTO> mostCommonKeywords { get; set; }
```

And the list is sorted like following:

```
  mostCommonKeywords = key.GroupBy(v2 => v2)
                 .Select(g => new CustomDTO { Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
                 .OrderByDescending(e => e.Count).Distinct()
                 .ToList();
```

Where Key is List of strings like following:

```
var key = new List<string>();
```

Each string element inside the key list consists of 3 words which I need to merge into 1 in case they are equal (or group them into one, whichever term you prefer more).

The grouping method like above gives me these results:

```
Samsung Galaxy S7   
Galaxy S7 edge  
Galaxy S7 Edge  
S7 edge SM  
Samsung Galaxy S7   
Samsung Galaxy S7
```

As you can see clearly there are duplicates here in this list of strings, and I need the results to look like this:

```
Samsung Galaxy S7   
Galaxy S7 edge  
S7 edge SM
```

So basically wherever a same string occurs,  I need to merge it into one...

What am  I doing wrong here??

Edit:  And here is how the CustomDTO class looks like:

```
 public class CustomDTO
    {
        public string Key { get; set; } 
        public int Count { get; set; }

        public List<int> Sales = new List<int>(); 
    }
```

Edit: The thing here is that I'm adding a sale number into each string which consists of 3 words to know which keyword how many sales....

This is how I've done it:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < filtered.Count; i++)
                {
                    foreach (var triad in GetAllWords(filtered[i]))
                    {
                        var sequence = triad[0] + " " + triad[1] + " " + triad[2];
                        key.Add(sequence + " " + lista[i].SaleNumber);
                    }
                }
```

This is the part that makes the string "not unique":

```
 + lista[i].SaleNumber
```

Edit:

mostCommonKeywords list is a list of CustomDTO object which consists of:

```
public string Key { get; set; } 
public int Count { get; set; }
public List<int> Sales = new List<int>();
```

And suppose that at the end of everything the list looks like this:

```
      Key           Sales
Samsung Galaxy S7    5
Galaxy S7 edge       4
Galaxy S7 Edge       4
S7 edge SM           3 
Samsung Galaxy S7    6
Samsung Galaxy S7    7
```

How can I now find all these duplicates and sum them so that the list looks like following:

```
Samsung galaxy S7 18 
Galaxy S7 edge 8 
S7 edge SM 3
```

Comment: Have you tried a HashTable instead of a List, or maybe, call the .Distinct()?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates in the list using linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606679/remove-duplicates-in-the-list-using-linq)

Comment: @rmjoia I tried with Distinct() , it didn't work... Haven't tried with HashTable yet

Comment: where do you get your list from? database or something?

Comment: I tried it and it should works fine. Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/R7HVoO

Comment: Hmm that's odd, I must be doing something wrong here then... :/

Comment: Your original LINQ code seems to work for me (with the exception of the case differences)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you group the strings you can pass a `IEqualityComparer<>` to ignore case:

```
var keywords = key.GroupBy(v2 => v2, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                  .Select(g => new CustomDTO { Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
                  .OrderByDescending(e => e.Count).Distinct()
                  .ToList();
```

EDIT:

If items are something like `{ string Key, int Sale }`, you can `Sum()` the `Sale` property like this:

```
var keywords = items.GroupBy(v2 => v2.Key, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                  .Select(g => new CustomDTO
                  {
                      Key = g.Key,
                      Count = g.Count(),
                      Sales = g.Sum(k => k.Sale)
                  })
                  .OrderByDescending(e => e.Count).Distinct()
                  .ToList();
```

Note: `CustomDTO.Sales` must be `int` type, not `List<int>`.

Comment: Arturo, quick question, imagine if I left the duplicate strings like that.. Would there be a way for me to loop through them and find all duplicate strings and sum their sales all at once?? As you can see I have a list of sales for each keyword... I would have to loop through the entire list and find identical ones and sum them, and THEN add the duplicates  (i.e. add only 1 duplicate string into new list to ensure I have no duplicates in it ) into the new 3rd list which would contain all the sum of sales...

Comment: @User987: I don't understand exactly what you ask, please add an example.

Comment: I've updated my original question ,can you look into it ?

Comment: Is there any way  to make it with Sales being List<int>?

Comment: If you want the sales values (not sum) you can do `Sales = g.Select(k => k.Sale).ToList()`, but in your output you are showing a single value that is the sum, so `Sales` must be an integer, not list.

Answer (score 1):

`GroupBy` takes a second parameter where you can specify the EqualityComparer.

This should work. You do not need the second `Distinct` call

```
var mostCommonKeywords = key.GroupBy(v2 => v2,StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        .Select(g => new CustomDTO { Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
        .OrderByDescending(e => e.Count)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: quick question, imagine if I left the duplicate strings like that.. Would there be a way for me to loop through them and find all duplicate strings and sum their sales all at once?? As you can see I have a list of sales for each keyword... I would have to loop through the entire list and find identical ones and sum them, and THEN add the duplicates (i.e. add only 1 duplicate string into new list to ensure I have no duplicates in it ) into the new 3rd list which would contain all the sum of sales...