# Filter List using linq for remove duplicates items

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a class Person with properties (dni, Name, lastname, Adate(dd/mm/yyyy)).
The List of Person is populated with duplicated items.

```
12345         Jhon      scofield       7/10/2015
24627         Liz       Pereira        7/06/2014
32313         Brian     O'conner       12/06/2012
12345         Jhon      scofield       7/10/2016
32313         Brian     O'conner       12/06/2015
```

i try:

```
var x = ListFamily.GroupBy(p => p.dni).OrderByDescending(t => t.Adate)
                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

but t.Adate is not recognize

```
var y = ListFamily.OrderBy(z => z.Adate).First();
```

but this return only one family object.

How to remove the duplicates person using latest date in the list with linq (lambda expression)?
i mean, i want to return a list without duplicates dnis and show the person with latest date like this

```
24627         Liz       Pereira        7/06/2014
12345         Jhon      scofield       7/10/2016
32313         Brian     O'conner       12/06/2015
```

Comment: Try this: Might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606679/remove-duplicates-in-the-list-using-linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to project the grouping rows for each group to select the record with the highest date using `OrderByDescensing` with `Select` after `GroupBy` like :

```
var x = ListFamily.GroupBy(p => p.dni)
                  .Select(g=>g.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Adate)
                              .FirstOrDefault()
                         );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
var result= ListFamily.GroupBy(p => p.dni)
                      .Select(g=>g.OrderDescending(p=>p.Adate).FirstOrDefault());
```

You need to order each group in descending order to select the latest.

Answer (score 0):

When you `GroupBy` you get an enumerable of groups, so you need to select for each group the entry with the latest date:

```
ListFamily.GroupBy(p => p.dni, (_, g) => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Adate).FirstOrDefault());
```