# Group list by items in sub list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

**I have this list:**

CustomerA

- Cod123
- Cod456

CustomerB

- Cod456
- Cod789

CustomerC

- Cod888
- Cod999

**I want to return this using LINQ:**

CustomerA

- Cod123
- Cod456

CustomerC

- Cod888
- Cod999

Because **CustomerA** and **CustomerB** have the same cod: **Cod456**

My classes:

```
    public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Cod> Cods { get; set; }
}

public class Cod
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

My attempt **not** build in GroupBy line.

```
            var customersOK = customersDuplicatedCods
                    .GroupBy(p => p.Cods.Number)
                    .Select(g => g.First())
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Can you give us actual C# classes? You're example is too vague to work with.

Comment: Ok. I give my classes.

Comment: It sounds like you don't actually want them grouped, you just want duplicates removed.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't actually want them grouped, you just want duplicates removed.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606679/remove-duplicates-in-the-list-using-linq) Q&A explains how to do that.

Basically you would create an `IEqualityComparer<Customer>`

```
class DistinctItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<Customer> 
{
    public bool Equals(Customer x, Customer y) 
    {
        return x.Cods.Intersect(y.Cods).Any();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Customer obj) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And call it by `customers.Distinct(new DistinctItemComparer())`