# Distinct method doesn't work for class with overriden Equals

Tags: c#, distinct, ienumerable, equals

I created class with overriden Equals. The problem is that Distinct method doesn't work for my class.

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Item1 { get; private set; }
    public int Item2 { get; private set; }

    public MyClass(int item1, int item2)=>(Item1,Item2)=(item1,item2); 


    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as MyClass;

        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return (this.Item1 == other.Item1 && this.Item2 == other.Item2);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass x = new MyClass(1, 0);
        MyClass y = new MyClass(1, 0);
        var list = new List<MyClass>();
        list.Add(x);
        list.Add(y);


        bool b = x.Equals(y));  //True
        var distincts = list.Distinct(); //Doesn't work, contains both
    }
}
```

How can I fix that and why it doesn't use my Equals in Distinct?

Comment: `MyClass` should also override `GetHashCode` since it overrides `Equals`. There's even a compiler warning for it.

Comment: You should also override the `GetHashCode` method like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38434457/2946329

Comment: All set methods need `GetHashCode`(before `Equals` is used). But in general you should always implement `GetHashCode` **and** `Equals` together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `IEquatable<MyClass>` in `MyClass` and provide your own implementation of `GetHashCode` and `Equals` method.

see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) for more information.

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Item1 { get; private set; }
    public int Item2 { get; private set; }

    public MyClass(int item1, int item2)=>(Item1,Item2)=(item1,item2); 


    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as MyClass;

        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return (this.Item1 == other.Item1 && this.Item2 == other.Item2);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {

        return this.Item1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Distinct` [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Returns distinct elements from a sequence by using the **default equality comparer** to compare values.

Let's see [what the default equality comparer does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The `Default` property checks whether type T implements the `System.IEquatable<T>` interface and, if so, returns an `EqualityComparer<T>` that uses that implementation. Otherwise, it returns an `EqualityComparer<T>` that uses the overrides of **`Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashCode` provided by T**.

So basically, to make this work, you either:

- implement `GetHashCode` as well
- implement `IEquatable<T>`
- Call the overload of `Distinct` that accepts a custom equality comparer.

If I were you, I would choose the second one because you need to change the least of your code.

```
class MyClass: IEquatable<MyClass> {
    ...

    public bool Equals(MyClass obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return (this.Item1 == obj.Item1 && this.Item2 == obj.Item2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to override `GetHashCode` as well:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return Item1; // or something
}
```

`Distinct` first compares the hashcodes, which should be computed faster than the actual `Equals`. `Equals` is only further evaulated if the hashcodes are *equal*  for two instances.