# how to check uniqueness of an array list items in c#.net

Tags: c#, string, arraylist, distinct

I have an arrayList with below data in C#.net so I want to check uniqueness for only 3 items in the stings in arraylist items .uniqueness over ID,date,name
"ID;date time;name;code" ofcourse I want only date section of datetime to be unique not both date and time  section

```
"1;06/07/2017 11:17:16;out;0"
"1;06/07/2017 11:27:16;out;2"
"1;06/07/2017 11:28:16;out;0"
"1;06/07/2017 11:20:16;out;3"
```

so I want to distinct this arraylist because of duplicate date and ID and out
please help me to solve this.

Comment: This really isn't code, this is just a sample of your data.  What have you tried already?

Comment: dear  maccettura : i could not find any solution for this problem

Comment: So [you've tried nothing and you're already out of ideas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QG8Yr5tkyTg&feature=youtu.be&t=11s)?

Comment: ArrayLists exist in C# for backwards compatibility only. There is no valid reason to ever use them in new code. Use a generic List<T> instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates in the list using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606679/remove-duplicates-in-the-list-using-linq)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is using LINQ. I would highly recommend using a `List<string>` instead of `ArrayList`. You can do distinct in the following way

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;

ArrayList list = new ArrayList() {
    "1;06/07/2017 11:17:16;out;0",
    "1;06/07/2017 11:27:16;out;2",
    "1;06/07/2017 11:28:16;out;0",
    "1;06/07/2017 11:20:16;out;3"
};

var distinctEnumerable = list.Cast<string>()
    .GroupBy(x => {
        var items = x.Split(';');
        var dateParts = items[1].Split(' ');
        return string.Join(";", items[0], dateParts[0], items[2]);
    })
    .Select(x => x.Key);
```

You can convert the `IEnumerable<string>` to `List<string>` or an `string[]` or some other convenient container if you wish to.

The main logic here is that, I `GroupBy` the List using the first 3 parts which you need distinct and then select the Key of the group, which will give us the distinct list.

[Live Code Demo Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DQIuYv)

Comment: dear Vikhram : only 3 elements are important. ID ,date and string. if these items are the same .duplicated items must be removed

Comment: @ Vikhram :OFcourse I want date section of datetime not both date and time

Comment: @ Vikhram I tested your code it returns 2 items.but I expected only 1 item      because items are "1;06/07/2017 11:17:16;out;0"
"1;06/07/2017 11:27:16;out;2"
"1;06/07/2017 11:28:16;out;0"
"1;06/07/2017 11:20:16;out;3" and all IDs and date parts and names are the same

Comment: @Vikharm I want the result to be only "1;06/07/2017 11:17:16;out;0"

Comment: I am running your code and see the result .it returns 2 items I am sure

Comment: @Shayan Probably. You should be able to see the logic I have built and adapt it to your situation, potentially by parsing it differently