# How to avoid duplicate value in list Using C# in unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I am newbie in unity  and use C#, actually i am python developer i try to make a list which can holds only unique Values and if some duplicate value come it will not allow to  enter in list

```
List<int> iList = new List<int>();
    iList.Add(2);
    iList.Add(3);
    iList.Add(5);
    iList.Add(7);
```

list =[2,3,5,7]

**in python we just do this to avoid duplicate in list **

```
if(iList.indexof(value)!=-1){
iList.append(value)
}
```

But what should we do in C# to achieve very similar results Thanks 
Your effort will be highly appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606679/remove-duplicates-in-the-list-using-linq/38434457#38434457

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C# List has similar method:
`if (!iList.Contains(value)) iList.Add(value);`

Alternatively you can use a `HashSet<int>`. There you don't need to add any conditions:

```
var hasSet = new HashSet<int>(); 
hashSet.Add(1);
hashSet.Add(1);
```

Comment: Thaks Brother Highly appreciated For time and answer

Comment: Note that using a HashSet will not preserve the order of the entries

Answer (score 6):

In C# we (can) just do this to avoid duplicate in list:

```
if (iList.IndexOf(value) == -1 ) {
    iList.Add(value);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the condition be `iList.IndexOf(value) == -1`?

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin: You are right, thanks; although I don't know Phyton, maybe OP made the same mistake.

Answer (score 4):

A HashSet would ensure you only have one instance of any object. Or a Dictionary if you want to have a key that is different to the object itself. Again dictionaries do not allow duplicate keys.

A HashSet will not throw an exception if you try to put in a duplicate it just won't add it.

A dictionary will throw a duplicate key exception.

Comment: Note that using a HashSet/Dictionary will not preserve the order of the entries

Answer (score 3):

Consider to build your own type of **List** that will never add duplicates

```
public class NoDuplicatesList<T> : List<T>
{
      public override Add(T Item) 
      {
         if (!Contains(item))
                base.Add(item);
      } 
}
```

Comment: But HashSet<T> is not a List<T> actually, it has no indices and it can't get an item by index