# LINQ Query that omits any duplicate IDs

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two tables. For simplistic reasons will call them Table A and Table B,

> Table A:

**ID** *int(PK)*

**customername** *varchar*

**customeraddy** *varchar*

**inservice** *boolean*

**etc** *varchar*

**etc** varchar

> Table B:

**PKID**
*int(PK)*

**ID**
*int()*

**linename *varchar***

Just looking for a LINQ query that can select all values from a joined table of **Table A** and **Table B** on the ID column where inservice == "true" that omits any duplicates based on ID (because Table B has multiple duplicates of ID).

So far this is what i have:

```
from x in db.tableA
join y in db.tableB on x.id equals y.id
where x.inservice == "true"
select y);
```

Comment: Which record you want to keep?

Comment: I want to keep any records that do not have duplicate IDs

Comment: Thats something else than _"omitting any duplicates based on ID"_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates in the list using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606679/remove-duplicates-in-the-list-using-linq)

Comment: You need to use an left outer join to get items in tableB that is not in table A : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: You need to `GroupBy` ID and then use `Count` to select the groups where the count is 1.

Comment: Hey @NetMage can you elaborate more on that? i feel like that's definitely the right way to go but i'm not too experienced with doing that using LINQ

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `inservice` is `bool` as in your table description and not `string`, and assuming you want both tableA and tableB rows where tableB has only one matching row,

```
var AjoinB = from x in db.tableA
             where x.inservice
             join y in db.tableB on x.id equals y.id
             group new { x, y } by x.id into xyg
             where xyg.Count() == 1
             select xyg;
```

Comment: So I think the query works fine but i am getting an error saying that i can't implicitly convert type <x,y> to the type defined in my ViewModel. this would be a ASP.NET MVC issue?

Comment: @user10192547 I think you will need to ask a separate question or show more code in this question explaining your purpose.