# Remove duplicate entries for 2D List in C#

Tags: c#, generic-list

I'm trying to remove example duplicate entries from this 2D List.

I've already tried using the `.Distinct().ToList()` method as highlighted in [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606679/remove-duplicates-in-the-list-using-linq) for 1D Lists but it doesn't seem to work for me here.

My code so far:

```
List<List<float>> xyvertices = new List<List<float>>();
xyvertices.Add(new List<float>());
yvertices[0].Add(2);
xyvertices[0].Add(4);

for (int a = 1; a < 6; a++)
{
    xyvertices.Add(new List<float>());
    xyvertices[a].Add(a+1);
    xyvertices[a].Add(a+3);
}
xyvertices = xyvertices.Distinct().ToList();
Console.WriteLine("count:" + xyvertices.Count + "\n");

for (int i =0; i<xyvertices.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(xyvertices[i][0]);
    Console.WriteLine(xyvertices[i][1]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

The above code runs but nothing changes.

How can I make this work? Thanks

Comment: for non-standtart List(or arrays) in your case  `List<List<float>>`, you must implement [IEqualityComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I'm looking for the output List to be 2D, in the same format as the input

Comment: @Cgameworld help us help you - share the output you expect

Comment: @Mureinik the expected output is to have only one copy of (2,4) which was added twice.

Comment: Though I agree with you the description "nothing changes" is not a good statement of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Distinct` is comparing the `List`s, and as the first two Lists are distinct, even though they contain the same two numbers, they are not Equal.

Your outer List is a list of x,y pairs so rather than code these as arbitrary Lists of floats, you can use a Tuple. For example:

```
List<(float, float)> xyvertices = new List<(float, float)>();
xyvertices.Add((2, 4));
for (int a = 1; a < 6; a++)
{
    xyvertices.Add((a+1,a+3));
}

xyvertices = xyvertices.Distinct().ToList();
Console.WriteLine("count:" + xyvertices.Count + "\n");
for (int i = 0; i < xyvertices.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(xyvertices[i]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Incidentally, comparing `float`s for equality is not good practice as they are not a precise type, use `Decimal` or `int` as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq GroupBy and gruop by first and second element as follows :

```
xyvertices = xyvertices.GroupBy(x=>new {first= x[0],second= x[1] })
            .Select(x=>new List<float> { x.Key.first, x.Key.second })
            .ToList();
```

Output :

```
count:5

2
4

3
5

4
6

5
7

6
8
```