# How do I generate a Dictionary without duplicate values?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```cs
public class DataClass
{
  public int Number1 {get; set;}
  public int Number2 {get; set;}
}

List<DataClass> list = new List<DataClass>();
list.Add(new DataClass {Number1= 1, Number2 = 100});
list.Add(new DataClass {Number1= 2, Number2 = 100});
list.Add(new DataClass {Number1= 3, Number2 = 101});
list.Add(new DataClass {Number1= 4, Number2 = 102});
list.Add(new DataClass {Number1= 5, Number2 = 103});
list.Add(new DataClass {Number1= 6, Number2 = 104});
list.Add(new DataClass {Number1= 7, Number2 = 104});
```

As you can see, I have a duplicate values for `Number2` (i.e., two `DataClass` objects with `Number2` set to `100`, and two set to `104`). I want to generate a dictionary like the one below which excludes these duplicates:

```
Key = 1, value = {Number1 = 1, Number2 = 100}
                 {Number1 = 3, Number2 = 101}
                 {Number1 = 4, Number2 = 102}
                 {Number1 = 5, Number2 = 103}
                 {Number1 = 6, Number2 = 104}

Key = 2, value = {Number1 = 2, Number2 = 100}
                 {Number1 = 7, Number2 = 104}
```

I would like to receive an optimal algorithm for solving this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicates in the list using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606679/remove-duplicates-in-the-list-using-linq)

Comment: It would be nice to see at least an attempt at solving this yourself.

Comment: I don't understand the logic of your keys.  How is 1 the key for both (1,100) and (6,104)?

Comment: What if you had three duplicates? i.e. also `list.Add(new DataClass {Number1= 8, Number2 = 104});   `

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear to me if you want to handle the situation where you might have more than just a duplicate (i.e. three or more of the same `Number2`). I'll add another `DataClass` so you can see how to handle more than 2.

Also, it's unclear if you want the output to be a (1) `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>` or a (2) `Dictionary<int, List<DataClass>>`. I'll provide you with both.

```
List<DataClass> list = new List<DataClass>()
{
    new DataClass { Number1 = 1, Number2 = 100 },
    new DataClass { Number1 = 2, Number2 = 100 },
    new DataClass { Number1 = 3, Number2 = 101 },
    new DataClass { Number1 = 4, Number2 = 102 },
    new DataClass { Number1 = 5, Number2 = 103 },
    new DataClass { Number1 = 6, Number2 = 104 },
    new DataClass { Number1 = 7, Number2 = 104 },
    new DataClass { Number1 = 8, Number2 = 104 },
};
```

(1)

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>> result =
    list
        .ToLookup(x => x.Number2)
        .SelectMany(xs => xs.Select((x, i) => new { x.Number1, x.Number2, i }))
        .GroupBy(x => x.i)
        .ToDictionary(
            gxs => gxs.Key + 1,
            gxs => gxs.ToDictionary(x => x.Number1, x => x.Number2));
```

(2)

```
Dictionary<int, List<DataClass>> result =
    list
        .ToLookup(x => x.Number2)
        .SelectMany(xs => xs.Select((v, i) => new { v, i }))
        .GroupBy(x => x.i, x => x.v)
        .ToDictionary(
            gxs => gxs.Key + 1,
            gxs => gxs.ToList());
```

The output I get from (2) is:

[image: result 2]

Comment: thank you very much. This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<DataClass> list = new List<DataClass>();
list.Add(new DataClass { Number1 = 1, Number2 = 100 });
list.Add(new DataClass { Number1 = 2, Number2 = 100 });
list.Add(new DataClass { Number1 = 3, Number2 = 101 });
list.Add(new DataClass { Number1 = 4, Number2 = 102 });
list.Add(new DataClass { Number1 = 5, Number2 = 103 });
list.Add(new DataClass { Number1 = 6, Number2 = 104 });
list.Add(new DataClass { Number1 = 7, Number2 = 104 });

var unique = new Dictionary<int, DataClass>();
var repeated = new List<DataClass>();
var result = new Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<DataClass>>();

foreach (var obj in list)
    if (!unique.TryAdd(obj.Number2, obj))
        repeated.Add(obj);

result.Add(1, unique.Values);
result.Add(2, repeated);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<DataClass> list = new List<DataClass>();
        list.Add(new DataClass {Number1= 1, Number2 = 100});
        list.Add(new DataClass {Number1= 2, Number2 = 100});
        list.Add(new DataClass {Number1= 3, Number2 = 101});
        list.Add(new DataClass {Number1= 4, Number2 = 102});
        list.Add(new DataClass {Number1= 5, Number2 = 103});
        list.Add(new DataClass {Number1= 6, Number2 = 104});
        list.Add(new DataClass {Number1= 7, Number2 = 104}); 
        var outPut = SplittedOutPut(list); 

private static Dictionary<int,IList<DataClass>> SplittedOutPut(IList<DataClass> fullList)
 {
      List<DataClass> Number1 = new List<DataClass>();
      List<DataClass> Number2 = new List<DataClass>();
      foreach (DataClass item in fullList)
      {
        if(!Number1.Exists( _ => _.Number2 == item.Number2))
            Number1.Add(item);
        else
            Number2.Add(item); 
      }

    var output = new Dictionary<int, IList<DataClass>>();
    outPut.Add(1,Number1);
    outPut.Add(2,Number2);
    return output;
  }
```

**Side Note**: One might think of using C# GroupBy Linq clause for this, but I just want to point out that LINQ group-by is not the same thing as a SQL group-by.   A SQL group-by only produces the grouping keys as the result.  A LINQ group-by is a hierarchical query that returns a sequence of groups, where each group contains the key and all the elements (rows) that made up the group. Thus it will be a much more expensive query than just traversing a list, which I have portrayed above.