# How to ignore extra results that I consider duplicates based on property?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

It might a long shot, but here we go. Let's suppose I have the following document definition:

```
public class Test1 {
    public ObjectId Id {get;set;}
    public int NonUniqueId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Using `IMongoCollection<Test1>`, I can filter the results to documents the ones where `Name = "somevalue"`, sort by `Price` and return 10 rows only.

```
var builder = Builders.Filters;
var filter = builder.Where(x=>x.Name == "somevalue");

var result = await collection.Find(filter).SortBy(x=>x.Price).Limit(10).ToListAsync();
```

Now to the question at hand. If more than one document is returned by the filter (with `Name = "somevalue"`) and `NonUniqueId` occurs more than once in that set, I would like to exclude duplicates `NonUniqueId` and return just the one with the lowest `Price`.

This logic is quite easy to implement in the code: fetch 10 results, if any of them are 'duplicates' (i.e. `NonUniqueId` occurs more than once), keep the one with the smallest price and run another search excluding this `NonUniqueId`. However, it requires multiple DB calls which is not great (up to 10 in the worst case).

In MongoDB (with C# driver), is there a way to ignore these 'duplicate' results based on the property and, ideally, return just the min of another property (or anything to the same effect)?

Answer (score 2):

give this pipeline a try:

```java
db.Product.aggregate([
    {
      $match: { Name: "book" }
    },
    {
      $sort: { Price: 1 }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$NonUniqueId",
        product: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
      }
    },
    {
      $replaceWith: "$product"
    }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/sqSjiXQhdlF

**update:** added c#

c# version is a bit inconvenient due to the projection needed:

```cs
var result = collection.AsQueryable()
               .Where(p => p.Name == "book")
               .OrderBy(p => p.Price)
               .GroupBy(p => p.NonUniqueId)
               .Select(g => new Product
               {
                   Id = g.First().Id,
                   Name = g.First().Name,
                   NonUniqueId = g.First().NonUniqueId,
                   Price = g.First().Price
               })
               .ToList();
```

test program:

```js
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverFlow
{
    public class Product : Entity
    {
        public int NonUniqueId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            new DB("test");

            var result = DB.Queryable<Product>()
                           .Where(p => p.Name == "book")
                           .OrderBy(p => p.Price)
                           .GroupBy(p => p.NonUniqueId)
                           .Select(g => new Product
                           {
                               ID = g.First().ID,
                               Name = g.First().Name,
                               NonUniqueId = g.First().NonUniqueId,
                               Price = g.First().Price
                           })
                           .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah... The projection will be the issue here. The collection has got 100000s of documents. I don't particularly fancy downloading all of them, but you can run a raw query from the driver. Does the limit shot circuit the group by?

Comment: @Dawid you can limit without an issue. the limit is imposed on the cursor afaik.

Comment: @DawidO thought you might be interested in a better way to run raw queries using c#. have a look at [this library](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities/wiki/13.-String-Templates) i've written.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something obvious here, I can't do `collection.AsQueryable()` because I don't want to download the entire collection on my local machine. With regards to the library, could you provide more detail how to integrate it with the code sample I provided?

Comment: @DawidO here you go: https://gist.github.com/dj-nitehawk/bda542ca93609fe12a670ccab89dc1d2

Answer (score -1):

Try the `Distinct` method, as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1606686/4795075) answer. You can even define a custom `Equals` function (by defining a class that implements `IEqualityComparer`) that performs the checks you need to perform

Comment: I don't need to compare C# objects. I want Mongo to do the heavy lifting for me.