# Compare 2 lists of the same type and remove duplicates

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to evaluate 2 list of a type called 'AdditionalInformation' this type has a property of Code

```
IList<AdditionalInformation> lis1
IList<AdditionalInformation> lis2
```

I'm merging both lists

```
List<ICrmCdsAdditionalInformation> mergedList = lis1.Union(list2).ToList();
```

What I need to do is evaluate the 'Code' property value on the merged list and if the property value is duplicated on any of the objects in my merged list remove all but one of the duplicated objects.

Merged list looks like this:

```
 ICrmCdsAdditionalInformation importerAi1 = new CrmCdsAdditionalInformation
    {
        Code = "Duplicate",
    };

  ICrmCdsAdditionalInformation importerAi2 = new CrmCdsAdditionalInformation
    {
        Code = "Duplicate",
    };

   ICrmCdsAdditionalInformation importerAi3 = new CrmCdsAdditionalInformation
     {
        Code = "Unique1",
      };
   ICrmCdsAdditionalInformation importerAi2 = new CrmCdsAdditionalInformation
     {
        Code = "Duplicate",
     };
```

I need to remove all but one of the "Duplicates" So my result should look like:

```
   ICrmCdsAdditionalInformation importerAi1 = new CrmCdsAdditionalInformation
    {
        Code = "Duplicate",
    };

   ICrmCdsAdditionalInformation importerAi3 = new CrmCdsAdditionalInformation
     {
        Code = "Unique1",
      };
```

Comment: Does it matter which one you'll keep?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicates in the list using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606679/remove-duplicates-in-the-list-using-linq) Freddy's answer should help you

Comment: @Magnetron has the right link, to answers for this.  Using either linq groupby or a custom IEqualityComparer will both solve the problem.  If you have to do this from multiple spots using the comparer can prevent duplicating the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `Enumerable.Union` in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netcore-3.1).
Create an `IEqualityComparer` class:

```cs
class AdditionalInfoComparer : IEqualityComparer<ICrmCdsAdditionalInformation> {
    public bool Equals(ICrmCdsAdditionalInformation x, ICrmCdsAdditionalInformation y) {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;
        return x.Code == y.Code;
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

    public int GetHashCode(ICrmCdsAdditionalInformation info) {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(info, null)) return 0;

        return info.Code;
    }
}
```

Then just,

```cs
var mergedList = list1.Union(list2, new AdditionalInfoComparer());
```