# How do I delete duplicate values from List<object>?

Tags: c#

I made myclass and put it in a list.

In this list, if there is an 'MyClass' with the same address, I want to leave only one 'MyClass' with the smallest signal.

For example,

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int signal { get; set; }
    public int Address { get; set; }
}

static List<MyClass> myClasses = new List<MyClass>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.Id = 1;
    myClass.signal = 2;
    myClass.Address = 1234;
    myClasses.Add(myClass);

    myClass.Id = 1;
    myClass.signal = 4;
    myClass.Address = 5678;
    myClasses.Add(myClass);

    myClass.Id = 2;
    myClass.signal = 3;
    myClass.Address = 1234;
    myClasses.Add(myClass);

    myClass.Id = 2;
    myClass.signal = 3;
    myClass.Address = 5678;
    myClasses.Add(myClass);
}
```

In the above situation I would like to leave something like below in myclasses.

```
myClass.Id = 1;
myClass.signal = 2;
myClass.Address = 1234;

myClass.Id = 2;
myClass.signal = 3;
myClass.Address = 5678;
```

I think we can solve it with Linq, what should I do?

Comment: What's the criteria of identifying duplicate items?

Comment: Maybe duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606679/remove-duplicates-in-the-list-using-linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, your sample code in OP would result in same item being copied over again and again as you are referring to same object `myClass`. This would result in the following in your List.

[image]

Assuming, that was a mistake while reproducing the issue, you could recreate your intended List as following.

```
var myClasses = new List<MyClass>
{
        new MyClass
        {
            Id=1,
            signal=2,
            Address = 1234
        },
        new MyClass
        {
            Id=1,
            signal=4,
            Address = 5678
        },
        new MyClass
        {
            Id=2,
            signal=3,
            Address = 1234
        },
        new MyClass
        {
            Id=2,
            signal=3,
            Address = 5678
        },
};
```

Now assuming the criteria for duplicate is `MyClass.Id`, You could now Group the List with `Id` and then sort each sub-group with `signal`, picking up the smallest.

```
myClasses.GroupBy(x=>x.Id).Select(x=>x.OrderBy(x=>x.signal).First());
```

This would produce the desired result as

[image]

Comment: Why `.ToList()` when the `List<>` is not kept?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That was a mistake, have corrected it now. Thanks